# ::Base part meaning in ActiveRecord::Base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What does ::Base part mean in Person < ActiveRecord::Base class declaration?
I'm new to ruby and from what I've gathered so far, Person < ActiveRecord should be used.
Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

::Base is a class in module ActiveRecord. One of the things modules do is provide namespacing in Ruby. In Ruby you don't inherit from a module but you can mix it in using the include statement.

May I suggest picking up the [Pickaxe](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9) book or reading [Why's (Poignant) Guide to Ruby](http://poignant.guide/).

Comment: Mike, thanks,
I really need to pick up the pickaxe, pun intented ;-)

Answer (score 6):

in Ruby, `::` accesses static class or module constants. `ActiveRecord::Base` indicates that the `ActiveRecord` class or module has a static inner class called `Base` that you're extending.

**Edit:** as Mike points out, in this case `ActiveRecord` is a module...

Comment: ActiveRecord is defined as a module in Rails, http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/base.rb

Answer (score 6):

`::` is a unary operator that lets you access a constant, module, or class defined inside another class or module. It is used to provide namespaces so that method and class names don't conflict with other classes by different authors.

When you see ActiveRecord::Base in Rails it means that in Rails `ActiveRecord::Base`  is something like this

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base
  end
end
```

This means that a *class* called `Base` is inside a *module* `ActiveRecord` which is then referenced as `ActiveRecord::Base`

For better understanding of :: operator, just go through this example from [tutorialspoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm) :

```
MR_COUNT = 0        # constant defined on main Object class
module Foo
  MR_COUNT = 0
  ::MR_COUNT = 1    # set global count to 1
  MR_COUNT = 2      # set local count to 2
end
puts MR_COUNT       # this is the global constant
puts Foo::MR_COUNT  # this is the local "Foo" constant
```